# How to change network connection order?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, wifi

I have multiple network access in the same area.

How can I reorder the priority to which the connections are made ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**System Preferences → Network → Wi-Fi → Advanced**

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Go to your System Preferences → Network.

Alternatively, you could click the WiFi icon in the menu bar, then choose Open Network Preferences.

In the preference pane, you can make your Mac prefer Ethernet connections over WiFi, for example, or the other way around.

[image]

If you click the “settings” symbol next to the `+` and `-` buttons, you’ll be able to select “Set Service Order”:

[image]

If you continue to WiFi → Advanced you can set the order of WiFi networks specifically by dragging them around:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Go to System Preferences>Network>Advanced>Wi-Fi:

[image: Network]
[image: Advanced]
[image: drag wifi into the order you prefer]

As you can see, you can drag the networks into the order you prefer.

Comment: The "drag in progress" screenshot is a nice touch.

Answer (score 3):

Open System Preferences, and select the `Network` preference pane.  Once opened, select the <kbd>Advanced</kbd> button.

[image]

From within the resulting sheet, you can drag the order of your networks around to fit your needs.

[image]

Once done, make sure you hit <kbd>Apply</kbd> on the bottom right of the Network pane to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've accessed the Network>Advanced pane that allows you to reorder the priority of your network list as described in this thread, then drag your desired network connections to the top of the list to give them priority over others.