# How to change which Aiport Express a MBP is connected to?

Tags: wifi, airport, time-capsule, internet

So I have a Time Capsule which creates my wireless network, and I have an airport express which extends the network. However, when I open Airport Utility, it says that my Macbook Pro is connected to the Time Capsule, not the Airport Express, even when I'm sitting right next to it. How do I change it so that it connects to the Express?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change network connection order?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45702/how-to-change-network-connection-order)

Comment: The linked question is about connecting to two SSID / not steering a connection to a shared network with two or more base stations.

Comment: In theory the MBP should pick up the strongest signal automatically. Why does it matter to you whether the MBP connects to the TC or the APE?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to change which access point you connect to.

Using the GUI

Open network in your system preference
use the Join other networks and find the airport Express in your WiFi choices
check the Automatically join this network.
click on Advanced and move that access point to the top of your list.

If for some reason this does not work then use the Terminal

There are 2 or more ways to select the network using Terminal.

There is the [ifconfig command line](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ifconfig.8.html), which is in depth network setting, I would not use that one right now.

the other is [Networksetup command line](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) which is replacement for the GUI method mentioned above.

You would use the output from the airport command and the networksetup utility to adjust properties such as connecting to a new Wi-Fi network.

First, scan for networks with the "`airport -s`" option (you can skip this if you know your SSID you want to use.

and then use the SSID of the listed networks with the

`networksetup -setairportnetwork <device name> <network> [password]` command.

should be the "en0" which is your WiFi

or

```
networksetup -switchtolocation "location name"
```