# Set a default Wifi network

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I am new on Apple world. I have a MacBook Pro mid 2014. I have an issue and don't know how to solve it.

When I am at home and turn my Mac on, it tries to connect on the first free wifi network which is a low signal one. I want to force it and connect on my home network instead. Now, I do it manually by disconnecting and connecting to the right one.

Is there any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change network connection order?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45702/how-to-change-network-connection-order)

Comment: Could you upload a screen shot of how you connect? Is home network an WiFi network or ethernet or something else?

Comment: It proved that the answer was the right one. Didn't know that there is a preferred list and it was lower that the free one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up `System Preferences`. Click `Network`. After you select `Wi-Fi` on the left, click `Advanced...` . Drag your home network to the top under `Preferred Networks`. Click `OK` then `Apply`.